# compiling latest version of libx264 for ffmpeg fails on Ubuntu 17.10 (Artful)

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, x264

I'm running Ubuntu 17.10 on bare metal.
My plan is to compile the latest version of ffmpeg including the encoding libraries.

I'm following the CompilationGuide of ffmpeg (https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu).

I fail creating x264.
The compilation phase works fine. The linking fails with a relocation error.

```
/usr/bin/ld: libx264.a(cabac-a-8.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against hidden symbol `x264_8_coeff_last16_sse2' can not be used when making a shared object
```

The complete logs are here on Pastbin: https://pastebin.com/MLJTJmXK

There are no old libs or executables on my machine.
I tried to compile with sudo to avoid permission issues.

Any idea what might go wrong?

EDIT: After the comments that many other didn't have problems I set up a virgin version of Ubuntu 17.10 with [Digital Ocean](http://www.digitalocean.com) and ran into exact the same problem

Comment: nope. I deleted all directories and started over again. In the logs there was a hint to use -fPIC. Therefore I run configure with `--enable-shared`. That helped me to overcome the immediate problem. I had to run `ldd`to make the lib in /usr/local/lib know to the system. Now everything seems to run fine. But I still wonder why I can't compile `x264` in static mode. I use gcc 7.2.0. I wonder if there could be anything on my system which interferes with the build process.

Comment: perhaps a compiler problem? which gcc is in 16.04 installed?

Comment: for an additional test I set up a virgin Ubuntu 17.10 at Digital Ocean. It failed with the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related to [GCC hardening for 16.10](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/PIE) which has added `--enable-default-pie` to `gcc`. You can check by viewing the output of `gcc -v`.

Try adding `--enable-pic` to the x264 configure (no need for `--enable-shared` if you are following the [guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu)).

Comment: This did the trick!